# Get original names of files with a function like fileInput (R shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to select some files in the browser like with `fileInput` in Shiny but I only need their paths as a character and nothing else. I do not want to upload them (but it's no problem if it is done anyway). When I use `fileInput` the result is a `data.frame` containing the paths of the files in a temporary folder with the names i.e. 0.csv, 1.txt, 2.pdf ... But I need the original filenames (with or without the full path). Is there any way to achieve this in a fast and 'non-hacky' way?

Comment: lets assume, I want to upload a file called "test123.csv". How should the result look like and where do you want to store or display the result?

Comment: The result should look like "temporarypath/test123.csv" instead of "temporarypath/0.csv" where the uploaded file is really stored. I want to add several files in my case and I want to have a vector with all the paths with the format that I mentioned.

Comment: What exactly did you try? The `$name` property should give you the original file name supplied by the browser while the `$datapath` property gives you the path to the uploaded file.

Comment: Sorry, I was revised on friday, I needed weekend, my question was silly. With the help of your comment I can now rename the files with `$name` and that's all I need for my purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The original names are saved in the variable

```
input$file1$name
```

However the "real" data (which is renamed as OP correctly pointed out) can be accessed via

```
input$file1$datapath
```

where `file1` is the InputId of the function `fileInput()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a very important reason why this is not possible: **Security**

JavaScript has **no accress to the file System**, so you will not to able to get the full paths of the user. One option is your force your user to use a path, but well... he can lie there of course. Maybe do it like this

You could only use it like this:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Test"),
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv")
  ),
  textInput("path", "Please enter the full path of your file"),
  tableOutput("pathtable")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


  testdf <- reactive({

      data.frame(
        ID = 1,
        file = input$path
      )
  })

  output$pathtable <- renderTable({

    if(input$path == "") {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      testdf()
    }

  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. I am stupid, I asked the wrong question. I do NOT need the whole path. I only need the correct file name instead of numbers and the file extensions like 0.csv ... Sorry!

Comment: hi. did you manage to solve this? I have an issue with images (uploaded individually, must be like this). They are all named 0.jpg and when I generate a docx document, they are all the same first image